# The FluentMigrator throws when want to migrate due to wrong assembly binding

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I use FluentMigrator in NET7 and wanted to migrate my migrations. I use the:

`dotnet tool install -g FluentMigrator.DotNet.Cli`

And I have ran command:

```
dotnet fm migrate -a Conversations.API.dll -p postgres -c "omitted"
```

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
And I got:

> 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

When I use `--allowDirtyAssemblies` flag, then I get exception as below:

```
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for System.Runtime, loading it from disk anyway. pathomitted/System.Runtime.dll
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for Google.Protobuf, loading it from disk anyway. pathomitted/Google.Protobuf.dll
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Google.Protobuf.IBufferMessage' from assembly 'Google.Protobuf, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604'.
```

That's my `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.151" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentMigrator" Version="3.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentMigrator.Console" Version="3.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentMigrator.Runner.Postgres" Version="3.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.55.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="7.0.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="PasetoBearer.Authentication" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.6.122" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\get_conversations.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\get_conversation_messages.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance I'd assume one of your elements needs updated or you updated without adjusting assembly binding redirects?

Comment: You mean NuGet packages when saying "elements"? I dont know what assembly binding redirect is. I will edit my question and add `.csproj`.

Comment: Since you're using Grpc.AspNetCore, it might be pulling in a specific version of Google.Protobuf as a dependency. You might want to explicitly add the Google.Protobuf package reference to your project and ensure it's using a compatible version.

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="[latest_version]" />

Comment: I have 8 packages and it results with 30 transitive packages (packages used as dependency of these 8 packages). Do you think its a right way to solve this problem? Installing every 30 dependencies?

Comment: Ok, I did it and still doesnt work. The same exceptions are thrown

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).